# Using Avalonia with netstandard

Tags: .net-standard-2.0, avaloniaui, avalonia

I try to run my Avalonia app on .net framework. However, when I downgrade targetframework to netstandard2.0, AppBuilder becomes unavailable and I just couldn't figure out, how to fix that problem.

I couldn't find any template, that targets .net framework or netstandard. Documentation contains nothing regarding this issue. The only thing I could find is [this](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/3235) Github issue. As I understood, AppBuilder is not supposed to be used in netstandard. Then, what is proper replacement for following code?

```
public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
    => AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
    .UsePlatformDetect()
    .LogToTrace()
    .UseReactiveUI();
```

## Edit:

As it was pointed out, netstandard can't be used as a target for Avalonia apps, but we can specify multiple targets. So I replaced

`<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>`

with

`<TargetFrameworks>net7.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>`

And it worked on .NET core and .NET Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netstandard2.0` isn't an actual .NET framework version: it's a [specification of the common API beteen .NET framework 4.6.1 and .NET core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0) (among others). As such `netstandard2.0` only makes sense as the target framework for libraries, not applications.

If you want your app to target .NET framework then you need to use a .NET framework version as the target framework, for example `net48` for .NET Framework 4.8.